# Http Url Intercepting through Burp Tool

Tags: security, weblogic, struts, ejb-3.0

There is end user having permission to delete a row from grid he clicks delete and request(url) will form  before it reaches to server i will intercept through burp suite tool and i will change the action from delete to copy such that instead of calling delete action in server side it will call copy method so how to avoid these I know that i need to do again a server side validation to overcome whether this user is having delete,add,edit,copy permissions .
I have many pages so instead of server side validation do I have any other approach to overcome this

Framework I am using 
1) Structs
2) EJB

Below is the reference  url
   userAction=deleteResource&formName=csm_SearchCriteria&documentId=listresources.application&previousFrame=listresources&frame=editresource&resourceName=EMA_BUSINESS_RULE&FW_SYS_ID=54b7c8a0e9ee43ef8649e6e54ddc6f32

After intercept url modify the action and again i will forward the request.
         userAction=copyResource&formName=csm_SearchCriteria&documentId=listresources.application&previousFrame=listresources&frame=editresource&resourceName=EMA_BUSINESS_RULE&FW_SYS_ID=54b7c8a0e9ee43ef8649e6e54ddc6f32

Can any one suggest how to over come this scenerio

Answer (score 2):

If the user is not supposed to be able to copy that row, access control must be enforced on the server. As the client can just send anything as you correctly described in the Burp example, you cannot prevent this on the client.

Theoretically you could store state on the client, for example user access rights encrypted/signed and with a timestamp, etc. so you don't have to query that again on the server, but on the one hand, it would increase risk quite a bit, on the other hand you would still have to enforce access control rules on the server, for each and every action.

Retrofitting security is hard. It's worth to design and implement applications with security in mind.